# Office Addin get screen position and bounding rect of ribbon buttons

Tags: c#, ms-office, excel-addins

I only found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366355/is-there-a-way-to-get-office-addin-ribbonbutton-screen-coordinates) about it, which hasn't been answered.

Is it possible to get the info at all?

So far, I've been able to get the screencoords of the ribbon itself but I wasn't able to get the position of the ribbon buttons.

Here the snippet which I use for getting the ribbon position and size:

```
RECT rect = new RECT();
GetWindowRect(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

this.ribbonRect.X = rect.Left;
this.ribbonRect.Y = rect.Top;
this.ribbonRect.Width = rect.Right - rect.Left;
this.ribbonRect.Height = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Ribbon"].Height;
```